# maximum recursion depth exceeded in comaprison for a length 1 list

Tags: python, string, list, pickle, fwrite

```
fuelcells[:1]
```

is just `['Honda FCX Clarity']` a length one list. Yet when I try

```
    with open('fuelcells.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(fuelcells[:1], f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

I get the following error,

```
in __getattr__
    if len(tag) > 3 and tag.endswith('Tag'):

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Help is highly appreciated. Thank you. In front of `in __getattr__` it prints

```
"*\bs4\element.py", line 1045,
```

So its signifying an issue with beautiful soup, even though the line has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Works on my machine. If I do `fuelcells = ['Honda FCX Clarity']`, then I can pickle `fuelcells[:1]` just fine. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: could it be because I was running similar code for pickling other lists? I have two before this one.

Comment: Sure, maybe. That's something you should be able to determine while you're constructing your MCVE.

Comment: Have you verified that `fuelcells` is actually a list? Some third party libraries (such as BeautifulSoup) provide custom data types that _look_ like lists when you print them, but are not actually lists.

Comment: I just checked the datatype of elements inside the list, and it was `bs4.element.NavigableString`, I changed it to `str` and it is working now. Thanks.